# Placing newly opened windows while having a window maximized?

Tags: 11.10, unity, window

I'm often working in a maximized window from which I'm opening new windows, that do not appear maximized. They are placed at the very top at the desktop in the way that I can not see the upper window decoration. The upper dock of the maximized window is in front of it. This is very unhandy, because I can not easily close or move the newly opened window. Is there a way to fix this behaviour? I played around with the Place Windows plugin in compiz but it didn't work at all.

Greetings, Wauzl

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fix it, but moving windows is also possible by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing the left mouse button and then dragging the window with the pointer anywhere on it.

Possibly you have to enable the plugin "Move Window" in `CompizConfig Settings Manager` before:

[image: move window plugin]

This should be a little bit easier then tinkering around with that hidden window bar.

Comment: Thanks, I was already doing that, but since I'm working with my touchpad instead of a mouse, this is not the ideal solution.